# How to integrate ASP.NET Identity with other site's authentication?

Tags: authentication, iframe, asp.net-identity

*Please note, I am asking for architecture/workflow ideas, not implementation. I am get stuck with this since months... all ideas I figured out have some "impossible to do" or "security nonsense" part.*

I would like to integrate authentication of 2 independent web sites. One of them is ASP.NET Identity (INNER), the other (OUTER) have custom form based authentication. The OUTER is implemented on LAMP. I know well programming ASP.NET Identity, and will solve the programming tasks in the other once I have an idea of the architecture and workflow.

The basic requirement is that the OUTER site may have pages which contain iframes with content from INNER. Accessing for both OUTER and INNER pages requires authentication, but I would like **authenticate** and **manage** users via the OUTER application. Knowing the identity of the user in the INNER page is mandatory.

Instant syncing of created/changed users on the OUTER is not a requirement, periodic one way replication from OUTER to INNER will do it. I know I can replicate everything of course *except* passwords.

Ideas:

1. Hooking login in OUTER in javascript then making a login call to
   INNER with the typed username/password. This creates the ASP.NET
   login cookie so an authenticated session is exist in the current
   browser window. (maybe I am wrong about this, but unfortunatelly
   this does not matter, because this is impossible by other reasons).
   This falls to "impossible to do" because the passwords can not replicated so on INNER side passwords obviuosly different
2. Creating an instant sync of users/passwords from OUTER to INNER, then
   hooking login in OUTER in javascript then making a login call to
   INNER with the typed username/password. This creates the ASP.NET
   login cookie so an authenticated session is exist in the current
   browser window. (is it true at all?). Unfortunately this is *so* complicated and error prone. (say we must catch password change actions too). Besides of this this case the OUTER app must create users in INNER which requires a technical user account, so all must done in server side in OUTER app.
3. Using a technical user for INNER and hooking login in OUTER in javascript and log in with the technical user to INNER sending the identity information (OUTER username). In server side in INNER switch the identity from the technical to the sent identity. This is the worst I ever heard: technical user password is exposed at client side, so it falls to "security nonsense"
4. Using a technical user for INNER and hooking login in OUTER in **server side** and log in with the technical user to INNER sending the identity information. In server side in INNER switch the identity from the technical to the sent identity. OK, this is not a "security nonsense". neither too complicated, however this case the "authenticated client" for the INNER is not the browser, instead the OUTER server app, so no cookies. All iframe requests sent to the INNER still not authenticated.
5. Same as 4, plus: Iframe is served by also the OUTER by proxying all request to the INNER. The client created in server side in OUTER first logs in (etc, etc just like in 4) then maintains a cookie container in its session. So when proxying all subsequent requests they will count as authenitcated request in the INNER app. Issue: It seems to be overcomplicated. Creating such a transparent proxy is not as simple as it seems. (Handling correctly POSTs and GETs, handling redirects, content types etc)
6. Some token based thing? Implement some API in OUTER and let the INNER ask back to OUTER to validate a request? This should be in every requests? (this case it really does not fit to ASP.NET Identity, no authenticated session created. This seems to not using ASP.NET identity so kinda reinventing the wheel.
7. ?

If either of the above are OK, but I had a mistake to evaluate them unusable, or anyone have a 7th idea please share it.